# angularjs for dropdown list

Tags: angularjs, selectlist

I have to *drop down list*.  First *dropdown* is:

```
<select ng-model="vm.eesAdminSetupData.Type"
class="form-control"  
id="Type"
name="Type"
required>
<option value="Form">Form</option>
<option value="List">List</option></select>

<select ng-model="vm.eesAdminSetupData.SettingID" 
class="form-control" 
id="SettingID" 
name="SettingID" 
ng-options="option.SettingID as option.SettingID + ' - ' + option.Name for option in vm.eesSettingIdOptions" >
<option ></option>
</select>
```

What I want to do is, once I select List, the other drop down should have a value of *blank* or *null*.  Is that possible?

Comment: <select 
                                    ng-model="vm.eesAdminSetupData.Type"
                                    class="form-control"  
                                    id="Type"
                                    name="Type"
                                    required
                                    >
                                    <option value="Form">Form</option>
                                    <option value="List">List</option>
                                           
                                </select>

Comment: Please add at least your current HTML code for the selects.

Comment: First:
<select 
                                    ng-model="vm.eesAdminSetupData.Type"
                                    class="form-control"  
                                    id="Type"
                                    name="Type"
                                    required
                                    >
                                    <option value="Form">Form</option>
                                    <option value="List">List</option>
                                           
                                </select>

Comment: Second:
<select 
                                    ng-model="vm.eesAdminSetupData.SettingID"
                                    class="form-control"  
                                    id="SettingID"
                                    name="SettingID"
                                   
                                    ng-options="option.SettingID as option.SettingID + ' - ' + option.Name for option in vm.eesSettingIdOptions" 
                                    >
                                    <option ></option>

Comment: Put it in the question not in comments!

Answer (score 0):

Just add an `ng-show` to your second `<select>` so it is only displayed when *List* is selected.

```
<select ng-model="vm.eesAdminSetupData.Type"
  class="form-control"  
  id="Type"
  name="Type"
  required>
    <option value="Form">Form</option>
    <option value="List">List</option>
 </select>

 <select
   ng-show="vm.eesAdminSetupData.Type == 'List'" 
   ng-model="vm.eesAdminSetupData.SettingID" 
   class="form-control" 
   id="SettingID" 
   name="SettingID" 
   ng-options="option.SettingID as option.SettingID + ' - ' + option.Name for option in vm.eesSettingIdOptions">
     <option></option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<select ng-model="vm.eesAdminSetupData.Type"
                class="form-control"  
                id="Type"
                name="Type"
                ng-change="changesettingsDropdown()"
                required>
                <option value="Form">Form</option>
                <option value="List">List</option>
                </select>

                <select ng-model="SettingID" 
                class="form-control" 
                id="SettingID" 
                name="SettingID" 
                ng-options="option.SettingID as option.SettingID + ' - ' + option.Name for option in vm.eesSettingIdOptions" >
                <option ></option>
                </select>
```

And in controller

```
$scope.vm = {};
$scope.vm.eesSettingIdOptions = [{"SettingID":"1","Name":"aaaa"}, {"SettingID":"2","Name":"bbbb"}];
$scope.changesettingsDropdown = function(){
    if($scope.vm.eesAdminSetupData.Type == "List") {
        $scope.SettingID = "0";
    }
}
```

I have added ng-change to first select element and changed ng-model of other select element

Answer (score 0):

Write a `ng-change` attribute in first `select` list like

```
ng-change=resetOtherDropdown()
```

in the above javascript function just reset the ng-model value of other drop down

```
resetOtherDropdown = function() {
    $scope.vm.eesAdminSetupData.SettingID = "";
}
```